# Read csv file fields with "^M" and multi lines with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am having a csv file. While analysing with spark (1.6.2) scala, I am not getting desired results due to some fields have "^M" and also multiple lines in single row in same carriage return in it. below is sample CSV file.

> 422,964,37,Very versatile,"I purchased this jacket in green, x-small a
>   while back and wasn?t 100% sure about it due to the size. i?m 5?3?,
>   117 lbs and a 33a and thought it was a little snug so i tried on the
>   small and that was way too big so i kept the xs. i have worn it a few
>   times and it does look great however i can only wear thin tops with
>   it. recently i purchased the black, x-small and this i love. it?s
>   looser then the green so i can get away with thicker tops. ^M i do
>   recommend both jackets. they are pricey for
>   what",5,1,2,General,Jackets,Jackets^M 423,1089,39,Small boobies
>   only,"I love this dress, i mean it si really pretty in person,
>   however, the breast area is just too small... i can't wear a bra with
>   it, and my ""older"" breasts just droop, not flattering. they are
>   barely covered... i am a bit disappointed at that, but if you are
>   smaller up there, i say give it a try... i am 115 lbs, 26.5 ion waist,
>   30dd and xs petite was great everywhere but chest.^M ^M colors and
>   fabric are great, i love that the different colors are different types
>   of fabric... too bad.",3,1,1,General Petite,Dresses,Dresses^M

I have removed '^M' by using below code. But this did not work.

> sed $'s/\r//' -i fie.csv

I have tried below code to read. It reads the file but after reading it shows text characters in first id fields while doing aggregation. I tried below code, with this it removes ^M but still it did not work.

> val a =
>   sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls",
>   "true").option("nullValue","null").load("pathtofile.csv")
>
> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
>
> a.withColumn("newReview", regexp_replace(col("`Review Text`"),
>   "[\r\n]", "")).drop($"`Review Text`").withColumn("Review",
>   regexp_replace(col("newReview"), "[\r]",
>   "")).drop($"newReview").withColumn("newReview",
>   regexp_replace(col("Review"), "[\n]", "")).drop($"NewReview")

Kindly help

Comment: Spark 1.6.2 is quite old. There seems to be a [bug with multi-line csv files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19610) that is fixed in 2.2.0. Did you try to run it with 2.2.0?

Comment: @werner Thank you. I thought so about the bug. I don't have spark 2.2.0. Will get it and try running it.